# Need help to filter different types of data in python

Tags: python

I want to filter the following data:

```
[{'param_2': '50'}, {'param_2': '10'} ,{'param_2': '100'}, {'param_2': '0.7'}, {'param_2': '1.8'}, {'param_2': '0.25'}, {'param_2': '0.18'}, {'param_2': '0.63'}, {'param_2': '1'}, {'param_2': '1.6-2.8'}, {'param_2': '1.6-2.1'},{'param_2': '1000'},{'param_2': '500'}]
```

I want to sort it in ascending order with:

sorted()

I have tried

```
param_2_filter = sorted(data, key=itemgetter('param_2'))
```

output:

```
0.18
0.25
0.63
0.7
1
1.6-2.1
1.6-2.8
1.8
10
100
1000
50
500
```

can someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you interpret values such as "1.6-2.1" in terms of sort order? Is the output you've shown what you're getting or what you want?

Comment: let's say these are values between two diameters, I get them in json format directly like this and then I have to order like this 
0.18
0.25
0.63
0.7
1
1.6-2.1
1.6-2.8
1.8
10
50
100
500
1000

Comment: Can we assume that '0. 18' is a typo?

Comment: yes it's was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to isolate items from the input data by type in order to perform discrete sorts then merge the results.

If you want D1' to appear **after** W1 then add *reverse=True* to the second sort call

Something like this:

```
data = [
    {"param_2": "50"},
    {"param_2": "10"},
    {"param_2": "100"},
    {"param_2": "0.7"},
    {"param_2": "1.8"},
    {"param_2": "0.25"},
    {"param_2": "0.18"},
    {"param_2": "0.63"},
    {"param_2": "1"},
    {"param_2": "1.6-2.8"},
    {"param_2": "1000"},
    {"param_2": "500"},
    {"param_2": "1.6-2.1"},
    {"param_2": "D1'"},
    {"param_2": "W1"},
]

def tv(v):
    pv, *_ = v.values()
    return tuple(float(x) for x in pv.split("-"))

def key_f(v):
    return tv(v)

def key_s(v):
    pv, *_ = v.values()
    return pv


data_f = []
data_s = []

for e in data:
    try:
        tv(e)
        data_f.append(e)
    except ValueError:
        data_s.append(e)

for e in sorted(data_f, key=key_f) + sorted(data_s, key=key_s):
    print(*e.values())
```

**Output:**

```
0.18
0.25
0.63
0.7
1
1.6-2.1
1.6-2.8
1.8
10
50
100
500
1000
D1'
W1
```

Comment: yes! it's works also, thank you

Comment: I want to improve sorting by adding in my data: {'param_2': "D1'"},{'param_2': "W1"}. how can I put them, for example, at the end of the sorting. NB: D1' is not a typo

Comment: @Arnok Where would "D1" appear in the sort order?

Comment: It's D1' not just D1 but I want to put it at the end of the sort list

Comment: @Arnok You want D1' to be **after** W1 ?

Comment: yes Let's say after W1

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following which implements the logic of your sort:

```
key = lambda d: [float(x.replace(" ", "")) for x in d["param_2"].split("-", 1)]   
param_2_filter = sorted(data, key=key)
```

Split on any dash and convert the bits into floats.

Comment: Wow! you've just solved my problem, thank you very much

Comment: I want to improve sorting by adding in my data: {'param_2': "D1'"},{'param_2': "W1"}. how can I put them, for example, at the end of the sorting. NB: D1' is not a typo

Comment: Define the key function as a real function and add that logic there: If a value does not fit in the float or range pattern, return some big value like `float("inf")` to put those at the end.

Comment: @user2390182 If you return float("inf") then you'll have no control over the order in which the values appear in the output because they will (effectively) be equal